# angularjs тестирование шаблона

Tags: angularjs, юнит-тесты, jasmine

1. angularjs
2. karma
3. jasmine

Настройка теста:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = controller('tasksController',{$scope: scope});
element = angular.element('<tasks-component></tasks-component>');
view = $compile(element)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

И сам тест:

```
console.log(view[0].querySelectorAll('.task')); // 5 элементов
ctrl.tasks = [1]; 
scope.$digest();
console.log(view[0].querySelectorAll('.task'));
expect(view[0].querySelectorAll('.task').length).toEqual(1);
```

Шаблон:

```
<div class="task" ng-repeat="task in $ctrl.tasks> 
</div>
```

Изначально "тасков" 5 штук , после этого я задаю изминение в модели через `ctrl.tasks=[1]` , после этого `view` , не изменяеться, там все так же 5 элементов. Что я делают не так и как обновить view ?